# Python Django Datetime Field that doesn't need all the information

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

I am looking to have a model that can accept a partially completed date as one of its field.

The field is supposed to represent the date that a historical event happened. Some of these events are only known to the year or month and not to the day.

Is there any graceful way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I think CharField is better if you just want to represent it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model, too! It may not be as efficient but if you're not looking to scale it a lot, this approach will have several benefits like easy and efficient look ups for events based on year/date.

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    date = models.ForeignKey(MyDate, related_name='events')

class MyDate(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    month = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    day = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```